# Xunit Tests fail with System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException : The operation was canceled

Tags: c#, xunit

I have some Xunit tests running after a code build that make some calls to an external API.  These are async calls.  On some of the test functions I make 3 of them returning values which are then used in the tests.

I get a  System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException : The operation was canceled. error with these.  Other tests which have similar await calls to an external API are fine.

I've had a hunt around google but can't find any fixes.

Code example below.

''''

```
[Fact]
        public async Task ClientDetailUpdateInterfaceTest()
        {

            var EnvironmentContext = "dev";
            var VerboseLog = false;
            string path = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location), @"TestFiles/ClientDetailUpdateTest.json");
            var triggerFile = File.ReadAllText(path);

            var awsCredentials = new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                { "accessKey", "abcd" },
                { "secretAccessKey", "efgh" }
            };

            Console.WriteLine("setting clientDetailUpdateInterface variables");
            var clientDetailUpdateInterfaceDetails = new InterfaceDetails(InterfaceSystem.ClientDetailUpdate);
            var clientDetailUpdatetInterface = new ClientDetailUpdateInterface(clientDetailUpdateInterfaceDetails, EnvironmentContext, null, null, VerboseLog);
            var clientDetailUpdate = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ClientDetailUpdate>(triggerFile);

            var transactionId = System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            var loggingId = "CDU-" + clientDetailUpdate.Reference;
            var seCredentials = GetSeCredentials();


            Console.WriteLine("moveFilesInS3ForSetup");
            var moveFilesInS3ForSetup = await MoveFilesInS3ForSetup(clientDetailUpdate, awsCredentials);
            Assert.True(moveFilesInS3ForSetup);

            Console.WriteLine("mimeAttachments");
            var mimeAttachments = await clientDetailUpdatetInterface.GetAttachments(clientDetailUpdate.Attachments, awsCredentials);

            Console.WriteLine("primaryAdviser");
            var primaryAdviser = await clientDetailUpdatetInterface.GetPrimaryAdviser(clientDetailUpdate.AdviserCode, transactionId, loggingId, seCredentials, awsCredentials);

            Assert.True(mimeAttachments.Count > 0);
            Assert.Equal("abcd", primaryAdviser.EmailAddress);

        }
```

''''

Stack trace below:

```
 Stack Trace:
     at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(String host, Int32 port, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ConnectAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean allowHttp2, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.CreateHttp11ConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.GetHttpConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncBuffered(Task`1 sendTask, HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts)
   at Framework.Services.SeApi.SendToSeApi(String jsonString, String endpoint, Dictionary`2 seCredentials, Dictionary`2 awsCredentials, String reference, String cpCode) in /codebuild/output/src024150111/src/Framework.Services/SeApi.cs:line 115
   at Framework.Services.SeApi.GetSeUser(String transactionId, String logId, Dictionary`2 seCredentials, Dictionary`2 awsCredentials) in /codebuild/output/src024150111/src/Framework.Services/SeApi.cs:line 681
   at SeInterface.AdviserNotifications.GetPrimaryAdviserEmail(Detail detail, String transactionId, String loggingId, Dictionary`2 seCredentials, Dictionary`2 awsCredentials) in /codebuild/output/src024150111/src/SeInterface/AdviserNotifications.cs:line 102
   at DigitalSeInterfacePostBuildTests.UnitTests.SetUpInProgressNotifications(InProgressNotification inProgressNotification) in /codebuild/output/src024150111/src/DigitalSeInterfacePostBuildTests/UnitTests.cs:line 410
   at DigitalSeInterfacePostBuildTests.UnitTests.InProgressNotificationsTest() in /codebuild/output/src024150111/src/DigitalSeInterfacePostBuildTests/UnitTests.cs:line 372
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
Results File: /codebuild/output/src024150111/src/testresults/_ip-10-247-110-119_2022-11-24_15_49_37.trx
```

Comment: What's the stacktrace of the exception? Where exactly is it thrown?

Comment: Hi, I added the stack trace.  The process is called as part of an AWS Code Build Pipeline.